# nohup on windows, exec without waiting for finish

Tags: php, windows, exec

Is there something like this for Windows?

```
exec("nohup /usr/bin/php -f sleep.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/39451/there-is-any-way-to-run-processes-in-the-background-in-windows-nohup-equivalent

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not that hard (albeit with some minor differences)...  You just need to use the [`WScript.Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(VS.85).aspx) COM object:

```
$shell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$shell->run($command, 0, false);
```

That's it...

Comment: What's the exception?  Try wrapping it in `try { $shell... } catch (Exception $e) { var_dump($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode()); }` to see what's causing it...

Comment: What's the error code?  And what's the full error?  And can you post the full code of the code that's generating the error?

Comment: ok your method works except that $shell->release(); throwing an exception

Comment: My command's I/O redirection `> somefile.txt` was not working until I added `%comspec% /c ` to the beginning of the command.

Comment: Great answer, took me a while to find it, COM needs to be installed: http://php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me (`pclose`, `start`, etc didn't). Also worth mentioning is the second parameter. 0 = hidden, 1 = activate and display, 2 = activate and minimize, etc.. Full list is here: http://ss64.com/vb/run.html

Answer (score 2):

By default, the Windows command [start](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true) does not wait for the child process.  You may want the `/b` switch to avoid creating a Command Prompt window.

```
exec("start /b c:\\php\\php.exe -f sleep.php");
```

Comment: Not completely true.  According to [the docs on `start`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true): it only does not wait if you are launching a GUI process.  If you are launching a console process it does wait (at least that's what it says for XP)...