# Launching a exe using php on windows

Tags: php, exec, wamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [nohup on windows, exec without waiting for finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197579/nohup-on-windows-exec-without-waiting-for-finish)

I will explain what I am trying to do:
I am trying to write a php page to launch my games by clicking images. I am trying to do this because I have attached a TV to my pc using hdmi and I want to be able to launch the games using my android phone.

I installed wamp on my pc that has the games on it. 
I am trying to run notepad to see if I can get it working. The problem is that the way I have it now works but it does not work as I need it to

```
<?php 
$notepad = '%windir%\system32\notepad.exe';
exec($notepad);
?>
```

This command launches notepad on the background and php keeps waiting for it to close down to continue (I think that is what it is doing as it seems to me that this is the normal behavior for exec).

Can any of you point me in the right direction on how to be able to run games using php?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with the [start](http://zeroflag.wordpress.com/2007/05/12/start-command/) command -

```
exec('start /b ' . $notepad);
```

Comment: This does the same thing. It still waits for it to close and doesn't actually start the gui